# unwanted skipping of whitespaces

Tags: c++, istringstream

I am using this to read input:

```
istringstream iss;
string typ, data;
char c1, c2;
iss >> skipws >> c1 >> typ >> noskipws >> c2 >> data;
```

input line can look like this `"   #text Markup used in this document is compatible with "` without quotes

what I want to achieve is that after my code variable data will contain `"Markup used in this document is compatible with "`

but instead this code ignores everything after word `Markup` even after I specified that I dont want it to skip whitespaces with `noskipws`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this `std::noskipws` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) you will see that it

> [...] disables skipping of leading whitespace by the formatted input functions

It doesn't really skip intermingled whitespace in input, reading into a string *always* stops on whitespace.

Instead you could use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get the remainder of the line.